# Promoting older alpha apk to beta

Tags: android, google-play, apk

On the google play console, is there a way to promote an older alpha apk to beta or production? Say my current alpha apk is 2.3.5. Is there a way to promote 2.3.3 to beta or production?

Comment: Did you not use the version control during the project? If you did, you can find the version in your commit history.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I found it under advance mode. Just go to the tab of interest such as "Production" or "Beta Testing"; then click on "switch to advanced mode" in the upper right corner. From there you can use the apk you want.